# How to unscrew faucet nut with no room to rotate?

Tags: faucet, sink, bathroom-fixtures

I need to remove a bottom mount sink faucet to replace a clogged cartridge. Unfortunately, there's no room to spin the faucet nut as it bumps into the edge of the sink. Any ideas?

[image: Under sink view, faucet nut with no room to spin]

Comment: If you can't rotate the nut, then disconnect the pipes and rotate the faucet.

Comment: Thats a surprisingly great idea, and one I wish I'd thought of! Will let you know how it goes. Thanks!

Comment: It might have happened that the faucet was put in place prior to the sink being fitted. Did that when I put the sink into my parents kitchen...

Comment: I think you're probably right. Anyway, your suggestion worked great, and the sink's good as new. 

Thanks!!

if you throw it up as an answer, I'll accept it and close the question. Thanks again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you cannot rotate the nut, then disconnect the pipes and rotate the faucet.

It might have happened that the faucet was put in place prior to the sink being fitted. It makes the nut easy to get to. I did that when I put the sink in my parents kitchen.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, I bring to you the basin wrench:
[image]

Comment: As the nut is hitting the sink as shown in the image, how will that work?

Comment: Appreciate the idea, and a basin wrench is a great tool. Unfortunately, as noted above, it won't work in this case as there's no room for the nut to rotate.